# Why does the pilot light on my Vermont Castings stove keep blowing out?

Tags: hvac

I bought a house with a sunroom heated by a Vermont Castings gas stove with a problem the HVAC/stove repair person hasn't solved by replacing the thermocouple, valve($$$) and taking apart and cleaning. I think it was installed in '89.

When the stove 'shuts off' after reaching the desired temperature, there is a 'poof' sound and occasionally the pilot light is blown out. This happens, on average, once a week. Sometimes 3 times a day. The pilot is all blue and covers all the pieces. The repair person is out of ideas, besides 'get a new one', which I can't do right now.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

I actually have one of these and there is a known issue with the Honeywell gas valves used. The solution (if it applies to your model) is to replace the valve.

Answer (score 0):

The poof is the main burner shutting off.

**Reasons the pilot is blowing out:**

- Excessive draft around the pilot. Try to externally reduce the air intake near the pilot, without restricting the air flow to the main burner.
- The main gas valve shutoff may be causing a "blooming" effect, where the flame flares as it shuts down, knocking out the pilot.
- If your system has an ODS (oxygen depletion sensor), it can shut off all gas. Try cracking a window as a test.  A CO monitor nearby isn't a bad investment.
- Both the pilot and the main burner have flame height adjustments.  Too high on the pilot could make it easy to blow out.  Too high on the main burner may cause the flare.  If you have access to the manual, this may or may not be a DIY adjustment.